# iOS 9 Chrome & Safari - devicemotion and deviceorientation does not work

Tags: google-chrome, mobile-safari, accelerometer, device-orientation, devicemotion

Unfortunately recently I have been able to register handlers for events on the window object for `deviceorientation` and `devicemotion`. However, I am now completely unable to get iOS 9.3 Chrome or Safari to access orientiation or motion information.

I have tried using TLS in case it was a security issue, and I have tried running the generic demo at https://github.com/dorukeker/gyronorm.js/tree/master/demo and https://www.audero.it/demo/device-orientation-api-demo.html.

All of those demos work fine with Chrome on Android.

Has something changed recently in iOS that has caused these events to no longer be available?  I have not been able find any info on a change other than a mention of tightening up security to require TLS.

Answer (score 1):

I found an ios device that is exhibiting this behavior. I dont have a solution, but I figure its worth posting here.

Its on ios 10.2.1, which is the latest version as of this post.

Its an iphone 6 plus (I cant imagine that is the issue)

It detects screen rotation, just not the intermediate rotations (i.e. alpha, beta, gamma)

I made sure the rotation lock is not on.

It has the larger text accessibility setting cranked up, but I checked that on another iphone and it did not make a difference.

Installed apps work with motion, so this is limited to safari. (oh, and I'm loading from https, so that should not be the culprit)

If anyone has seen this, I'd sure like to figure out what is causing it.